# Action bar not showing on new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

Action bar on new activities are not showing. I spent couple of hours on stack over flow and other websites on finding what can be the reason but i could not figure out the problem.

Can you please tell me what can be the reason and what will be the possible solution?

Following is my code

First i created : activity_forgot_password.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" 
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.reach2employee.ForgotPasswordActivity"
        >

            <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/appLogo"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
               android:src="@drawable/onlyitemployees_logo"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/forgotPasswordBtnText"
                android:textColor="#D08B3A"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
                />                

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/employerUsername"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:hint="@string/employerUsernameHint"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                />


            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#8eb534"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="@string/submitBtn"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                />                                       

</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Secondly i created ForgotPasswordActivity.java

```
public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);  
    }       

}
```

Third I have added some code in manifest file

```
<activity 
        android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="Forgot Password"
        ></activity>
```

Comment: We can't tell you the reason if you don't provide any code.

Comment: ok i provide you code. just a min

Comment: check: base class of new activity, theme of new activity

Comment: Maybe you are using a theme like "Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar" which make the ActionBar invisible, but i agree with Tanis.7x, without any code it's too hard to say it

Comment: @Tanis.7x I have updated my post. Please have a look now.

Comment: Do you provide a theme in your <application /> tag? Put your manifest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you are trying to get the native android action bar and not sherlok one's.....Does your activity extend `ActionBarActivity`? without that not possibly. After correcting the base class make sure your activity uses a theme that supports action bar.

Answer (score 1):

In my second Activity, I had to handle the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` handler again:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.topmenu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

and also the menu items' event handlers too:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_home:
            gotohome();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_admin:
            gotoadmin();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

UPDATE: I decided to create a base activity class that all my activities will inherit from. I put all the shared code in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar problem. My class was extending 'Activity' and not 'ActionBarActivity'. The Action Bar showed up after I extended the 'ActionBarActivity'.